# Building just one tool from Android source (AOSP)

Tags: android, linux, makefile, android-source

Currently I'm using the the [AOSP ROM Builder](https://aws.amazon.com/marketplace/pp/B00HZ3NSPE?ref=cns_srchrow) image on Amazon AWS to build Android.
The point is, I'm only interested in the external tool `grxmlcompile` that is built for the host (linux) in the path: `aosp/out/host/linux-x86/bin`
where the source is at `aosp/external/srec/tools/grxmlcompile`

I'm not very familiar with Linux and make files, hence my difficulty to get this going.

I would like to copy the source (if needed the whole tree) and build just this tool on another linux machine.

I can't find the make file I need to run to build just this part.

**UPDATE:**
Looks like `make out/host/linux-x86/bin/grxmlcompile` would do the job. I would still like to be able to port only the needed parts of the source tree to the build machine

Comment: Did my answer below, answer your question, so that you can only build that module?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`cd` to the top of your Android build source.

```
source build/envsetup.sh
cd external/srec/tools/grxmlcompile
mma
```

...or any directory, or sub-directory a makefile. From AOSP build/envsetup.sh

- m:       Makes from the top of the tree.
- mm:      Builds all of the modules in the current directory, but not their dependencies.
- mmm:     Builds all of the modules in the supplied directories, but not their dependencies.
         To limit the modules being built use the syntax: mmm dir/:target1,target2.
- mma:     Builds all of the modules in the current directory, and their dependencies.
- mmma:    Builds all of the modules in the supplied directories, and their dependencies.

external/srec was removed from the platform/manifest after android-5.1.1_r4 tag. So later, if you are using a manifest such as revision 5, 6 or later, you may need to do `git clone https://android.googlesource/platform/external/srec external/srec` to include that directory.

Comment: Even after running 'build/envsetup.sh' the mm, mma etc. commands are not recognized

Comment: I have not used these commands very much, even though being an Android ROM Developer I know about them, because I usually run full ROM builds only. However I just fixed up my answer with the correct method for building the grxmlcompile module only, with it's dependencies. I apologize about the delay. I left the other commands listed by AOSP's `build/envsetup.sh` in case you or anyone wants to build only a certain module without the dependencies (usually used for testing code build) or other modules. Some require input others do not. I hope this helps. I tested it in my build source first.

Comment: It took me seven minutes!!! :) Install: /home/sudosurootdev/source/android/VanirAOSP/out/host/linux-x86/bin/grxmlcompile
make: Leaving directory `/home/sudosurootdev/source/android/VanirAOSP'

#### make completed successfully (07:02 (mm:ss)) ####

Comment: If you are still having problems with this than you must be missing a local dependency or package. If you want a fresh build of it I uploaded it here: https://www.dropbox.com/s/xyrpwl4um8uve4r/grxmlcompile?dl=0 By the way, what do you use it for, translation or something? Also, why not fork it, add the dependencies and create a stand alone project by writing regular Makefiles to build it all so you are not wasting so much storage space???

Comment: Thanks for the detailed instructions. About youe suggestion to extract (fork) the part of the tree I need with my own makefile. I would like to do just that. But I don't have enough understanding of how to do it, or how to find all the dependencies I in the current tree. 
Or at least I can't do it in a reasonable time, without spending time learning how make works

Comment: When I say fork, I mean on github, also known as `git clone`. I can type up this for you but I am working on my kernel right now, and have a lot of users waiting for my LG G2 & LG G3 builds. So, I'll try to do it once I start my builds, cause I have a script that runs them all.

Comment: Just tried that and got the error message: `build/core/ninja.mk:159: build/kati/Makefile.ckati: No such file or directory`. This seems to be due to a half-completed switch to a different toolchain. Running `export USE_NINJA=false` right after `envsetup.sh` fixed this. Also, `libcxx` recently got replaced, the old version being renamed to `libcxx_35a`. You will need the old version under its old name.

Comment: for completeness: looking at https://android.googlesource.com/platform/manifest/, it seems `android-5.1.1_r33` is the last release that included `srec`. It is absent from `android-m-preview` and all released versions starting with 6.0.0_r1. (The corresponding java classes got dropped from `platform/frameworks/base` between `android-m-preview` and `android-m-preview-1`.)