# How to correctly clean up a module and rebuild it in AOSP?

Tags: android-source

The top directory of AOSP is ~/WORKING_DIRECTORY.  If I run

```
~/WORKING_DIRECTORY$ make
```

the whole system builds correctly.

According to [Building a particular module in the android source code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13139394/building-a-particular-module-in-the-android-source-code), https://stackoverflow.com/a/30671099/746461, if I need to rebuild art, I will

```
cd art
mm
```

However it throws error:

```
FAILED: out/target/common/cpplint/art__compiler__optimizing__nodes.h 
/bin/bash -c "(art/tools/cpplint.py --quiet --root=. --filter=-whitespace/line_length,-build/include,-readability/function,-readability/streams,-readability/todo,-runtime/references,-runtime/sizeof,-runtime/threadsafe_fn,-runtime/printf art/compiler/optimizing/nodes.h ) && (mkdir -p out/target/common/cpplint/ ) && (touch out/target/common/cpplint/art__compiler__optimizing__nodes.h )"
art/compiler/optimizing/nodes.h:3974:  Labels should always be indented at least one space.  If this is a member-initializer list in a constructor or the base class list in a class definition, the colon should be on the following line.  [whitespace/labels] [4]
art/compiler/optimizing/nodes.h:3978:  Labels should always be indented at least one space.  If this is a member-initializer list in a constructor or the base class list in a class definition, the colon should be on the following line.  [whitespace/labels] [4]
art/compiler/optimizing/nodes.h:3983:  Labels should always be indented at least one space.  If this is a member-initializer list in a constructor or the base class list in a class definition, the colon should be on the following line.  [whitespace/labels] [4]
art/compiler/optimizing/nodes.h:3987:  Labels should always be indented at least one space.  If this is a member-initializer list in a constructor or the base class list in a class definition, the colon should be on the following line.  [whitespace/labels] [4]
art/compiler/optimizing/nodes.h:3992:  Labels should always be indented at least one space.  If this is a member-initializer list in a constructor or the base class list in a class definition, the colon should be on the following line.  [whitespace/labels] [4]
art/compiler/optimizing/nodes.h:3996:  Labels should always be indented at least one space.  If this is a member-initializer list in a constructor or the base class list in a class definition, the colon should be on the following line.  [whitespace/labels] [4]
Done processing art/compiler/optimizing/nodes.h
Total errors found: 6
[  1% 108/10017] Building with Jack: out/ho...S/core-oj-hostdex_intermediates/classes.dex
ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
17:27:03 ninja failed with: exit status 1

#### failed to build some targets (13 seconds) ####
```

If I stay in ~/WORKING_DIRECTORY and call mm art, it seems to build correctly.

However, if I deliberately make a mistake in the source code, then run

```
~/WORKING_DIRECTORY$ mm art
```

it still builds, which means the new files are not compiled at all. See the screenshot.

[image]

What's the correct way of rebuilding a module?

Answer (score 1):

Cleaning of module:

```
cd $ANDROID_BUILD_TOP
make clean-module_name
```

art project have more than one target modules. You should use clean for them one by one.